# numpy convert 2D Integer Record to 2D floating point Record

Tags: python, numpy

I want to convert the record `[(1, 2, 3) (2, 2, 3)]` which is of integer type to floating type array as `[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (2.0, 2.0, 3.0)]`. However when I give the command `c.astype('float')` what I get at the output is `rec.array([ 1.,  2.])`. Why the other elements are deleted from the array?

Could someone please give me the correct solution?
Am I doing it the right way?

**Update**
I created the record from 3 different arrays like this - 
`d=np.rec.fromarrays([a, b, c], names='x,y,z')` in order to sort them and do some operations.

Here is the complete code -

```
a=[1,2]
b=[2,2]
c=[3,3]
d=np.rec.fromarrays([a, b, c], names='x,y,z')
print d
d.astype('float')
print d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inelegant but (apparently) working:

```
In [23]: import numpy as np

In [24]: a=[1,2]

In [25]: b=[2,2]

In [26]: c=[3,3]

In [27]: d=np.rec.fromarrays([a, b, c], names='x,y,z')

In [28]: d
Out[28]: 
rec.array([(1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<i4'), ('y', '<i4'), ('z', '<i4')])

In [29]: d.astype([(k, float) for k in d.dtype.names])
Out[29]: 
rec.array([(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (2.0, 2.0, 3.0)], 
      dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8'), ('z', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> np.array([(3, 0, 1)]).astype('float')
array([[ 3.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Does your code look different?

Comment: oh yes, I think I don't have a 2D array but a record. I have created a record from 3 different arrays like this - 
`c=np.rec.fromarrays([a, b, c], names='x,y,z')` 
what now then? :(

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... the only way I can coax it is:

```
a = np.rec.array([(1,2,3)])
np.array(list(a[0]),dtype='float')
```

for a N dimensional array:

```
a = np.array(map(list,d),dtype='float')
```

Hopefully someone else will come along with a better way...

Comment: your solution is good. however, i just want to convert each element in the record from integer to float. sorry, but i updated the code again to provide a minimum working example.

Comment: is it possible that the output still remains the record and not convert to array? :)

Comment: @RajTendulkar -- No idea.  I don't usually work with record arrays.  Of course, you could convert the array `a` back into a record array.  e.g.:  `d = np.rec.array(zip(*a),names='x,y,z')`